# List Namespace name, Namespace Age, and Status on Grafana using PromQL (prometheus) from Kubernetes Metric server

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana

We are having a Kubernetes cluster and using Prometheus + Grafana for monitoring and alerting.
We need to show a panel on Grafana that shows us the view (same as kubectl get namespaces) .
Currently we are able to get **name** and **status** column using the below PROMQL along with Hide options in Visualization section of Grafana.

**count(kube_namespace_status_phase) by (phase, namespace)**

But we also want to find the **AGE** from when a namespace was active/created.
We are not able to find **AGE** in any of the 4 kube metrics of namespace available -

1. kube_namespace_created
2. kube_namespace_status_phase
3. kube_namespace_lables
4. kube_namespace_annotations

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately as you already noticed there is no specific [metric](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics/blob/master/docs/namespace-metrics.md#namespace-metrics) that could be used to calculate the age of an object. The closest thing that you could use to achieve your goal would be to use `kube_namespace_created` which shows at what time namespace in Kubernetes was created.

I was also not able to find a proper Prometheus [operator](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#operators)/[function](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#functions) in order to make some kind of workaround PROMQL.

I am posting this answer as a community wiki. Feel free to expand on it as you wish.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen on other metrics regarding age that you need to multiply by 1000

So if you do;

```
kube_namespace_created * 1000
```

You would need to check/test but I've seen that used on other queries about finding the age of worker nodes.

Answer (score 0):

The following query returns the age of every Kubernetes namespace in seconds:

```
time() - kube_namespace_created
```

It uses [time()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#time) function, which returns the current time in seconds.